# Slim 3 - how to get all get/ put/ post variables?

Tags: slim, slim-3, psr-7

How I can get **all** `get/ put/ post` variables like  in Slim 2 for Slim 3?

Slim 2,

```
$allGetVars = $app->request->get();
$allPutVars = $app->request->put();
$allPostVars = $app->request->post();
```

How can I do that in Slim 3?

And, for example, `http://example.com/books/1?title=hello&content=world`

How can I get the params in `title` and `content` in Slim 3 now?

Slim 2,

```
$title = $app->request->get('title');
$content = $app->request->get('content');
```

How can I do that in Slim 3?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Get **all** `get/put/post` parameters:

```
//GET
$allGetVars = $request->getQueryParams();
foreach($allGetVars as $key => $param){
   //GET parameters list
}

//POST or PUT
$allPostPutVars = $request->getParsedBody();
foreach($allPostPutVars as $key => $param){
   //POST or PUT parameters list
}
```

Single parameters value:

```php
//Single GET parameter
$getParam = $allGetVars['title'];

//Single POST/PUT parameter
$postParam = $allPostPutVars['postParam'];
```

Comment: Thanks mate! Having a hard time looking for this

Comment: Hello. It doesn't work for me. The only thing who "works" is `$request->getHeaders();` and it adds _HTTP__ as a prefix. For example, if I use _length_ as a post parameters, with `getHeaders()` I'll get _HTTP_LENGTH_. I don't understand why. And `getParsedBody()` return basically _NULL_. Thanks!
PS: The strangest thing is: if I do `$request->hasHeader('length')`, i get the value of my parameter.

Comment: @TDK How are you sending the request and which version of Slim are you using?

Comment: @Davide I'm using Slim 3, and i'm sending the POST request through [Advanced REST client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) to test it.

Comment: @TDK are you sure you have the `Content-type` header set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Comment: @Davide Yes. I tried with other content-type juste to try. but still nothing. The result is `array(0) {}` and the request headers are this: `Start_lng: 2.6423183977058
Start_lat: 56.865296679535
Size: 0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: @TDK Maybe you could try to create a new question for this. Also add your exact version of Slim, your server and your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: @Davide Ok thanks. I did it here if you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37031274/get-post-put-parameters-with-slim-3.

Comment: Adding that the route signature  in this case is   `$app->get('/books/1', function ($request, $response, $args) { ...}`

Comment: Why is it so complicated? I could as well just use plain old `$_GET`

Answer (score 8):

To Get all request params:

```
$request->getParams()
```

Answer (score 6):

[Request Uri](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/request.html#the-request-uri): `getQueryParams()`

[Request Body](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/request.html#the-request-body): `getBody()`/`getParsedBody()`

It's not exactly what you are looking for but it comes pretty close.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `map()` method to combine get, post & put into a single route.

```php
$app->map(['GET', 'POST', 'PUT'], function(Request $request, Response $response, array $args)) { }
```

The first argument is an array of the HTTP methods that you want to match. The second parameter is the function that handles the request; pass a request, response and an array of arguments.

Comment: this does not answer the question.