# Get POST PUT parameters with Slim 3

Tags: php, rest, slim, slim-3

I'm trying to build a full REST API with Slim 3. It was quite easy with Slim 2. But now I've got some issues.

The POST and PUT route does not work has expected. I can't get the parameters.
I found the `$request->getHeaders()` on the documentations, which works but instead of getting for exemple the parameter `length`, I get `HTTP_LENGHT` and every parameters has this *HTTP_* prefixe.

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32668186/slim-3-how-to-get-all-get-put-post-variables) but `$request->getParsedBody()` return an empty array for me.

I'm testing my API with [Advanced REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) and this is an example of what I send as a POST request:

```
POST /test/barrier HTTP/1.1
 HOST: mydomain.com
 start_lng: 2.6423183977058
 start_lat: 56.865296679535
 type: Something
 comment: testcomment
 due_date: null
 content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

I'm using Slim 3.3.0.

Here is an example of what I get with `$request->getHeaders()`:

```
["HTTP_START_LAT"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(15) "56.865296679535"
  }
  ["HTTP_START_LNG"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(15) "2.6423183977058"
  }
```

One strange thing is, if I try do to `$request->hasHeader('length');` I get the value of my parameter, so that means, the name are correct. I really don't understand.

I just want to get the array of the parameters as `$app->request->post()` used to do in Slim 2.*. Thanks.

My `.htaccess` is like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /test

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]

<files db.config.ini>
    deny from all
</files>
```

Comment: You probably should send the data as POST body and not headers.

Comment: @Mika Yeah... Exactly... I was sure it was an error in the actual code and not just an human mistake, haha. Classic way to lose time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. My mistake, I just got it wrong in the testing app. I was writing all my parameters as headers form an not as data form...