# Is 'lang' a keyword in getQueryParams() of Slim Framework?

Tags: php, slim, php-5.6

While fetching parameters from url(GET Request):

```
http://localhost:8080/xyz/abc/1234?size=4&chunks=0_5&lang=0,1,2,3
```

I am able to access argument 1234 and params by:

```
$params = $request->getQueryParams();
$argument = $args['id'];
$size =  $params['size'];
$chunk = $params['chunks'];
```

But I am not able to access 'lang' by:

```
$lang = $params['lang'];
```

However changing the request parameter from 'lang' to 'langs' seems to work:

```
 http://localhost:8080/xyz/abc/1234?size=4&chunks=0_5&langs=0,1,2,3
```

Now I am able to access 'langs' by:

```
$lang = $params['langs'];
```

Why is this happening? Is this because lang is a keyword in getQueryParams()? I searched google but did not find a concrete answer. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank You for your time.

Comment: You need to use encode your url. Php function is urlencode(). Or you should check this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32668186/slim-3-how-to-get-all-get-put-post-variables]

Comment: `&lang` is probably being treated as `&lang;` which is a HTML entity.

Comment: What is the output of `$params = $request->getQueryParams(); print_r($params);`?

Comment: I have tested your code with Slim 3 / PHP 7 and can say that `lang` is working as expected. Do you have any special middleware or firewall? Try `print_r($_GET); exit;`

Comment: We have application that using `lang` as query string parameter and it is working as expected. May be there is code or middleware that somehow unset it?

Comment: Yes, there was a piece of code which was setting it to a default value. Thanks a lot.